# Automatically select Dropdown value based on the router id typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have this Autocomplete component on my Formik and here is a scenario of what I want to achieve. there is an index page with the list of service providers, a user will click on the service provider name and the the link will take the user to a page where they can update the service provider details. on that page , the service provider details are prepopulated to the text input fields but the service provider name is not displayed since it is a dropdown Autocomplete field so I want the service  provider name to be automatically selected on the dropdown the moment a user clicks on that list to edit the details. please help its a deadline project here is the code:

```
    const UpdateServiceProviderForm: FC<FormProps> = ({
    formRef,
    validateChange,
    handleLoading,
    serviceProvider,
}) => {
    const { AxiosRequest, response, error } = useAxiosRequest();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const { alertShow, alertMessage, alertType, setAlert, closeAlert } = useFormAlerts();

    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (serviceProvider) {
            formInitialValues.sp_id = serviceProvider?.sp_id;
            formInitialValues.sp_allocate_to = serviceProvider?.sp_allocate_to;
            formInitialValues.sp_assesor_code = serviceProvider?.sp_assesor_code;
            formInitialValues.sp_email_address = serviceProvider?.sp_email_address;
            formInitialValues.sp_repair_limit = serviceProvider?.sp_repair_limit;
            formInitialValues.sp_limit100_l = serviceProvider?.sp_limit100_l;
            formInitialValues.sp_limit150_l = serviceProvider?.sp_limit150_l;
            formInitialValues.sp_limit200_l = serviceProvider?.sp_limit200_l;
            formInitialValues.sp_limit250_l = serviceProvider?.sp_limit250_l;
        }
    },[serviceProvider]);

    //handling the update response
    useEffect(() => {
        if (response) {
            handleLoading(true);

            if (error) {
                setAlert({
                    show: true,
                    message: 'Failed to update service provider',
                    type: MessageTypes.Error,
                });
                handleLoading(false);

                return;
            }

            const responseData: RequestResponse<string> = response.data;

            if (!responseData.is_successful) {
                setAlert({
                    show: true,
                    message: responseData.message,
                    type: MessageTypes.Error,
                });
                handleLoading(false);

                return;
            }

            setAlert({
                show: true,
                message: responseData.message,
                type: MessageTypes.Success,
            });
            router.push('/admin/general/service-providers');
            handleLoading(false);
        }
    }, [response]);

    return (
        <div>
            <FormAlerts
                show={alertShow}
                message={alertMessage}
                type={alertType}
                handleClose={closeAlert}
            />

            {alertShow && <br />}

            <Formik
                initialValues={formInitialValues}
                validateOnBlur={validateChange}
                validateOnChange={validateChange}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}
                onSubmit={async (values, actions) => {
                    await AxiosRequest.PUT({
                        url: `/api/v1/serviceproviders/update`,
                        data: values,
                    });
                }}
                innerRef={formRef}
            >
                {({ values, setFieldValue }: FormikProps<any>) => {
                    return (
                        <Form>
                            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <Typography variant="subtitle1" marginTop={0.5}>
                                        Provider Details
                                    </Typography>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <InputField
                                        name={serviceProviderUpdateFormModel.sp_allocate_to.name}
                                        label={serviceProviderUpdateFormModel.sp_allocate_to.label}
                                        autoFocus
                                        fullWidth
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <InputField
                                        name={serviceProviderUpdateFormModel.sp_assesor_code.name}
                                        label={serviceProviderUpdateFormModel.sp_assesor_code.label}
                                        fullWidth
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <InputField
                                        name={serviceProviderUpdateFormModel.sp_email_address.name}
                                        label={
                                            serviceProviderUpdateFormModel.sp_email_address.label
                                        }
                                        fullWidth
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <Typography variant="subtitle1" marginTop={1}>
                                        Provider Limits
                                    </Typography>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <InputField
                                        name={serviceProviderUpdateFormModel.sp_repair_limit.name}
                                        label={serviceProviderUpdateFormModel.sp_repair_limit.label}
                                        fullWidth
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <InputField
                                        name={serviceProviderUpdateFormModel.sp_limit100_l.name}
                                        label={serviceProviderUpdateFormModel.sp_limit100_l.label}
                                        fullWidth
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <InputField
                                        name={serviceProviderUpdateFormModel.sp_limit150_l.name}
                                        label={serviceProviderUpdateFormModel.sp_limit150_l.label}
                                        fullWidth
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <InputField
                                        name={serviceProviderUpdateFormModel.sp_limit200_l.name}
                                        label={serviceProviderUpdateFormModel.sp_limit200_l.label}
                                        fullWidth
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <InputField
                                        name={serviceProviderUpdateFormModel.sp_limit250_l.name}
                                        label={serviceProviderUpdateFormModel.sp_limit250_l.label}
                                        fullWidth
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Form>
                    );
                }}
         

</Formik>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.